# Why case generates a different result in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT c1.customer_id, c1.name
FROM Orders o1
JOIN Product p1 USING (product_id)
JOIN Customers c1 USING (customer_id)
WHERE o1.order_date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-08-01'
GROUP BY c1.customer_id
HAVING (SUM(p1.price * o1.quantity) > 100 AND MONTH(order_date) = 6) 
AND (SUM(p1.price * o1.quantity) > 100 AND MONTH(order_date) = 7)
```

And

```
SELECT c1.customer_id, c1.name
FROM Orders o1
JOIN Product p1 USING (product_id)
JOIN Customers c1 USING (customer_id)
WHERE o1.order_date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-08-01'
GROUP BY c1.customer_id
HAVING sum(case when month(order_date) = '06' then price*quantity else 0 end)>=100 AND
sum(case when month(order_date) = '07' then price*quantity else 0 end)>=100
```

Why does the 1st query return an error: "Unknown column 'order_date' in 'having clause'" and the 2nd query doesn't fail? What difference does it make to use CASE in the HAVING statement?

Comment: In your first query you group by customer. Later you check if the customer's order date equals six or seven. The customer's order date? Which is the customer's order date? There can be many orders for a customer. This is why the DBMS rightly complains.

Comment: I'm doing the same grouping in both of them (by customer id). Wouldn't that take care of multiple orders for a customer?

Comment: No. In the second query you are not trying to access the order date after grouping by customer. In the second query you only access sums. `SUM(expression)` adds up row data, i.e. the expression inside `SUM` refers to the data of single rows. In your case "if the row's month is six then multiply the row's price with the row's quantity and use this in the sum; if this another month use 0 for this row in the sum". This should be 6 and 7 by the way, nt '06' and '07', as `MONTH` returns an integer, not a string.

Comment: As we're at data types :-) you should use date literals when dealing with dates, i.e. precede the strings that hold the ISO dates with the word `DATE`: `BETWEEN DATE '2020-06-01' AND DATE '2020-08-01'`. And when dealing with more than one table, you should qualify all columns, i.e `o1.order_date` instead of `order_date`, and `price`and `quantity` would probably become `o1.price` and `o1.quantity`, or maybe you are using the current product price `p1.price`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, the `case` expression produces a conditional aggregate, ie, depending on the case expression evaluating it returns one of two values, which are then aggregated using `sum`.

The single result of this aggregation is then compared with the filtering criteria `>=100` in order to include valid rows in the results. The `having` criteria is simply

`having sum(some resulting value) >=100`

However the first query is trying to combine a `where` criteria (`where month(order_date)=6`) with the result of the `having` aggregate. This is not valid SQL syntax, `having` operates only on the result of an aggregate, there is no aggregation happening with `order_date` here.

Comment: Thanks! If I understood your explanation correctly, I'm (somehow) adding a WHERE criteria in my having clause even though I'm not explicitly using WHERE. In that case, is there anything I should take into account to avoid this situation in the future?